# How do I map county-level data as a heatmap using FIPS codes (interactively?) in R

Tags: r, ggmap, tmap

I am hoping to create an interactive map that will allow me to create a plot where users can change the year and variable plotted. I've seen the package tmap be used, so I'm imagining something like that, but I'd also take advice for a static map, or another approach to an interactive one. My data is much, much, richer than this, but looks something like:

```
example <- data.frame(fips = rep(as.numeric(c("37001", "37003", "37005", "37007", "37009", "37011", "37013", "37015", "37017", "37019"), 4)),
                      year = c(rep(1990, 10), rep(1991, 10), rep(1992, 10), rep(1993, 10)),
                      life = sample(1:100, 40, replace=TRUE),
                      income = sample(8000:1000000, 40, replace=TRUE),
                      pop = sample(80000:1000000, 40, replace=TRUE))
```

I'd like my output to be a map of ONLY the counties contained in my dataset (in my case, I have all the counties in North Carolina, so I don't want a map of the whole USA), that would show a heatmap of selected variables of interest (in this sample data, `year`, `life`, `income`, and `pop`. Ideally I'd like one plot with two dropdown-type menus that allow you to select what year you want to view, and which variable you want to see. A static map where I (rather than the user) defines year and variable would be helpful if you don't know how to do the interactive thing.

I've tried the following (taken from [here](http://bcb.dfci.harvard.edu/~aedin/courses/R/CDC/maps.html)), but it's static, which is not my ideal, and also appears to be trying to map the whole USA, so the part that's actually contained in my data (North Carolina) is very small.

```
library(maps)
library(ggmap)
library(mapproj)
data(county.fips)
colors = c("#F1EEF6", "#D4B9DA", "#C994C7", "#DF65B0", "#DD1C77", 
           "#980043")

example$colorBuckets <- as.numeric(cut(example$life, c(0, 20, 40, 60, 80, 
                                                          90, 100)))
colorsmatched <- example$colorBuckets[match(county.fips$fips, example$fips)]

map("county", col = colors[colorsmatched], fill = TRUE, resolution = 0, 
    lty = 0, projection = "polyconic")
```

Comment: For interactivity have a look at the `shiny` and `leaflet` packages.

Answer (score 0):

Here's almost the whole solution. I had hoped some package would allow mapping to be done by fips code alone, but haven't found one yet. You have to download shapefiles and merge them by fips code. This code does everything I wanted above except allow you to also filter by year. I've asking that question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58205579/adding-an-interactive-filter-to-a-layered-leaflet-map-in-r), so hopefully someone will answer there.

```
# get shapefiles (download shapefiles [here][1] : http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2014/shp/cb_2014_us_county_5m.zip )

usgeo <- st_read("~/cb_2014_us_county_5m/cb_2014_us_county_5m.shp") %>%
  mutate(fips = as.numeric(paste0(STATEFP, COUNTYFP)))


### alternatively, this code *should* allow you download data ### 
### directly, but somethings slightly wrong. I'd love to know what. ####
# temp <- tempfile()
# download.file("http://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2014/shp/cb_2014_us_county_5m.zip",temp)
# data <- st_read(unz(temp, "cb_2014_us_county_5m.shp"))
# unlink(temp)
########################################################

# create fake data
example <- data.frame(fips = rep(as.numeric(c("37001", "37003", "37005", "37007", "37009", "37011", "37013", "37015", "37017", "37019"), 4)),
                      year = c(rep(1990, 10), rep(1991, 10), rep(1992, 10), rep(1993, 10)),
                      life = sample(1:100, 40, replace=TRUE),
                      income = sample(8000:1000000, 40, replace=TRUE),
                      pop = sample(80000:1000000, 40, replace=TRUE))
# join fake data with shapefiles
example <- st_as_sf(example %>%
                       left_join(usgeo))
# drop layers (not sure why, but won't work without this)
example$geometry <- st_zm(example$geometry, drop = T, what = "ZM")
# filter for a single year (which I don't want to have to do)
example <- example %>% filter(year == 1993)
# change projection
example <- sf::st_transform(example, "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84")


# create popups
incomepopup <- paste0("County: ", example$NAME, ", avg income = $", example$income)
poppopup <- paste0("County: ", example$NAME, ", avg pop = ", example$pop)
yearpopup <- paste0("County: ", example$NAME, ", avg year = ", example$year)
lifepopup <- paste0("County: ", example$NAME, ", avg life expectancy = ", example$life)

# create color palettes
yearPalette <- colorNumeric(palette = "Blues", domain=example$year)
lifePalette <- colorNumeric(palette = "Purples", domain=example$life)
incomePalette <- colorNumeric(palette = "Reds", domain=example$income)
popPalette <- colorNumeric(palette = "Oranges", domain=example$pop)

# create map
leaflet(example) %>%
  addProviderTiles("CartoDB.Positron") %>%
  addPolygons(stroke=FALSE,
              smoothFactor = 0.2,
              fillOpacity = .8,
              popup = poppopup,
              color = ~popPalette(example$pop),
              group = "pop"
  ) %>% 

  addPolygons(stroke=FALSE,
              smoothFactor = 0.2,
              fillOpacity = .8,
              popup = yearpopup,
              color = ~yearPalette(example$year),
              group = "year"
  ) %>%

  addPolygons(stroke=FALSE,
              smoothFactor = 0.2,
              fillOpacity = .8,
              popup = lifepopup,
              color = ~lifePalette(example$life),
              group = "life"
  ) %>%

  addPolygons(stroke=FALSE,
              smoothFactor = 0.2,
              fillOpacity = .8,
              popup = incomepopup,
              color = ~incomePalette(example$income),
              group = "income"
  ) %>%

  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups=c("income", "year", "life", "pop"),
    position = "bottomleft",
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
  )
```

**I'm still looking for a way to add a "year" filter that would be another interactive radio-button box to filter the data by different years.**

Comment: The issue with downloading counties data directly from census is here- "data <- st_read(unz(temp, "cb_2014_us_county_5m.shp"))" . The st_read needs a file name, but unzip does not return the file name. What worked for me was executing unzip(zip_file) first, then counties <- st_read(county_file)